# Get file from other Laravel application's storage folder

Tags: laravel, file-upload, filesystems, storage

I have two websites made with Laravel 8 uploaded into one server: **mywebsite/applicationA** and **mywebsite/applicationB**. File managements such as uploading and deleting images and documents were done in **applicationA**, so I added a new filesystem "disks" as per Laravel's documentation in config/filesystems.php:

```
'repository' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/repository'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

where as **applicationB** is some kind of online catalog which can view images and documents uploaded in **applicationA**. How can I view the uploaded files from **applicationB** in "Laravelish" way?

Comment: Since you have separate application, you can do API request from ApplicationB to ApplicationA to retrieve the data needed, then display in ApplicationB

Comment: you can also create a new driver in your filesystem config, if from ApplicationA, use absolute path to storage of ApplicationB, vice versa

Comment: IMHO nice way - make symlink from storageB to storageA and make standart filesystem

Comment: Since you are using the same server to host both applications so just create a new folder in your server and then create a symlink from storage-B to folder and then create another symlink from folder to storage-A just like this,
                     Storage-B --> New Folder --> Storage- A
I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Since your using two application how about using cloud storage like s3 for storage. then both application can access.